# Why is 1 Kings 22:47-50 missing in the LXX?

Tags: textual-criticism, hebrew-bible, septuagint, 1-kings

1 Kings 22:47-50 which describes the death of Jehoshaphat is missing in the LXX.

What could be the reason for having left out these verses?

> **1 Kings 22:47** ~ There was then no king in Edom; a provincial governor ruled. **48** Now Jehoshaphat built a fleet of trading ships[d] to go to Ophir for gold, but they never set sail—they were wrecked at Ezion Geber. **49** At that time Ahaziah son of Ahab said to Jehoshaphat, “Let my men sail with yours,” but Jehoshaphat refused. **50** Then Jehoshaphat rested with his ancestors and was buried with them in the city of David his father. And Jehoram his son succeeded him as king. ~ [NIV]